# conseguir mismo tamaño de cada linea shell linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Tengo un archivo con este formato (APP;tamaño en bytes;cantidad de ficheros;):

```
P09;54099;2601;
P15;0;0;
R00;3480902131;83348;
R05;1634899425;13781;
R15;5883278354;5386;
R25;554171689;1409;
```

Y mi problema es que luego necesito tratar ese fichero en otro sistema pero necesito que cada campo ocupe lo mismo (aunque sea rellenado las variables con ceros por la izquiera) para que asi las lineas ocupen todas lo mismo.

¿Alguien puede iluminarme con su sabiduría?

Comment: mírate esto por si te puede ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789729/how-to-zero-pad-a-sequence-of-integers-in-bash-so-that-all-have-the-same-width

Comment: ¿Podrías dar un ejemplo de cómo querrías exactamente que fuera el contenido de este fichero que das como ejemplo? ¿Qué intentaste?

Comment: Si si por supuesto. Mira necesitaría algo así:

Comment: Si tengo esto:
    P09;54099;2601;
    P15;0;0;
Necesitaría esto:
    P09;54099;2601;
    P15;00000;0000;

Comment: por favor, dale a [edit] para mostrar el ejemplo, pues en comentarios no se distingue bien el formato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te voy a pasar un script de ejemplo que completa los datos con ceros adelante.

Deberías crear un script.sh con el siguiente contenido:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    var="$(cat $1)"
    var1="-"

    while IFS='\n' read -ra ADDR; do
            for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
                    var1=""
                    while IFS=';' read -ra ADDR1; do
                            for j in "${ADDR1[@]}"; do
                                    var1="$( printf '%s%020d;' $var1 $j )"
                            done
                    done <<< "$i"
                    echo $var1
            done
    done <<< "$var"
```

Una vez creado script.sh puedes ejecutar el siguiente comando

```
sh script.sh tu_fichero
```

**tu_fichero**: es el archivo con los datos a tratar.

Este script te devolverá los datos a pantalla , si quieres enviarlo a otro archivo solo debes ejecutar:

```
sh script.sh tu_fichero > otro_fichero
```

Si quisieras que solo algunos campos sean los que deben llevar ceros adelante, pues solo debes tenerlos en cuenta con un if. Te paso un ejemplo donde el primer campo no le agrego nada y al resto si :

```
    #!/bin/bash

    var="$(cat $1)"
    var1="-"

    while IFS='\n' read -ra ADDR; do
            for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
                    var1=""
                    while IFS=';' read -ra ADDR1; do
                            iPosition=0
                            for j in "${ADDR1[@]}"; do
                                    if [ $iPosition = 0 ]; then
                                            # Aqui se arma el primer campo sin ceros
                                            var1="$( printf '%s%s;' $var1 $j )"
                                    else
                                            # Aqui se arma los otros campos con ceros. 
                                            # Observa que el que da el formato es el %020d 
                                            var1="$( printf '%s%020d;' $var1 $j )"
                                    fi
                                    iPosition="$(expr $iPosition + 1 )"
                            done
                    done <<< "$i"
                    echo $var1
            done
    done <<< "$var"
```

Te dejo comentado el código por si necesitas cambiar la cantidad de ceros adelante de los números.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Buf tio eres un bestia! a ver por ponerte un "pero" lo genera perfecto pero por ejemplo, para la app, no hace falta que escriba los ceros,simplemente para los que son números. ¿Qué cambios habria que hacer?
ahora mismo sale asi:
F3800000000000000000000;00000000000000102046;00000000000000000154;
F3800000000000000000000;00000000000000102046;00000000000000000154;

Comment: El que se encarga de poner los ceros es  var1="$( printf '%s%020d;' $var1 $j )" dentro del bloque for j in "${ADDR1[@]}"; . Antes de armar el var1 de nuevo deberías ponerle las condiciones que consideres..    Si me das un tiempo te amplio el ejemplo

Comment: Edité mi respuesta . Espero que te sirva

Comment: Bueno me habéis dejado sin palabras. Con la ultima edición es exactamente lo que quería. Si puedo hacer algo para que se os reconozca vuestros esfuerzos me decís y lo haré encantado. Muchisimas gracias!!

Comment: Por el momento marca que la respuesta es la correcta . Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Una solución con awk ( dependiendo del tamaño del archivo de entrada puede que la solución bash script sea mas eficiente/rápida )

`archivo.txt`

```
P09;54099;2601;
P15;0;0;
R00;3480902131;83348;
R05;1634899425;13781;
R15;5883278354;5386;
R25;554171689;1409;
```

---

**comando `awk`:**

```
awk -F ';' '{ printf("%s;%010d;%010d\n", $1, $2, $3) }' archivo.txt > resultado.txt
```

`resultado.txt`

```
P09;0000054099;0000002601
P15;0000000000;0000000000
R00;3480902131;0000083348
R05;1634899425;0000013781
R15;5883278354;0000005386
R25;0554171689;0000001409
```

**explicación del comando `awk`:**

`-F ';'` separar cada línea en campos/columnas usando `;` como separador

`printf` imprimir con formateo uno o mas valores

`%s` tratar valor como string

`;` imprimimos nuevamente para reestablecer el separador

`%010d` rellenar con `0`, hasta `10` posiciones, tratar valor como número `d`

`;` imprimimos nuevamente para reestablecer el separador

`%010d` rellenar con `0`, hasta `10` posiciones, tratar valor como número `d`

`\n` imprimir salto de línea

`$1, $2, $3` son los valores de las "columnas" o "campos" de cada línea ( `$0` es la línea completa )

`archivo.txt` es el archivo de entrada

`> resultado.txt` enviar la salida al archivo `resultado.txt`